# Detect when radio button is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form build in code behind.

What I am trying to do is detect when a radio button is checked, and when its checked changes.

I have the following

```
RadioButton radio = new RadioButton() { ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static, AutoPostBack=true, ID = "rbOther" + testEquipment.Id, GroupName = "grp" + testEquipment.Id, Checked = false };
radio.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radio_CheckedChanged);
```

testEquipment is a instance of a object that stores the some data.

```
tdBrandName.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static, ID = "txtBrandName" + testEquipment.Id, Text = serviceStationTestEquipment != null ? serviceStationTestEquipment.BrandName : string.Empty, Width = new Unit(300), Enabled = serviceStationTestEquipment != null ? serviceStationTestEquipment.Other : false });
tdBrandName.Controls.Add(new RequiredFieldValidator() { Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic, ControlToValidate = "txtBrandName" + testEquipment.Id, Text = "Required field", ErrorMessage = "Test Equipment Tab: Field is required", CssClass = "validationerror", Enabled = serviceStationTestEquipment != null ? serviceStationTestEquipment.Other : false, ID = ID = "reqValidator" + testEquipment.Id });
```

I then want to disable the textbox and the requiredfieldvalidator when the radio button is clicked. There is three ie. none, default, other

When other is selected the textbox must become enabled along with the required field validator.

```
void radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton check = sender as RadioButton;

        if (check == null)
            return;

        string Id = check.ID.Replace("rbOther", "");

        TextBox text = check.Parent.Parent.FindControl(string.Format("txtBrandName{0}", Id)) as TextBox;

        text.Enabled = check.Checked;

        RequiredFieldValidator validator = check.Parent.Parent.FindControl(string.Format("reqValidator{0}", Id)) as RequiredFieldValidator;
        validator.Enabled = check.Checked;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using jQuery, then you can try this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
     $("input[name$='grp']").click(function () {
         var value = $(this).val();
         id = value.replace("rbOther", "");
         $("#txtBrandName" + id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
         ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("reqValidator" + id), false);
        //Write your code HERE
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: So how will I then disable the RequiredFieldValidator?

Comment: Ok one more question, it appears this code isn't executing. When I use firebug and add a breakpoint to the script it doesn't stop on the breakpoint. Shouldn't this code be executed like on a page ready or something to actually add the click to the control?

Comment: The code is working I have tested it. Try inserting `debugger;` in your JS Code. The code will fire when you do the radio button selection. Also, you can try putting `alert(id);` in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample case . I have 3 items in a radibutton list and based on value selected i want a message to be displayed on the lable.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
<asp:ListItem Value="C">Contract </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="I">Independent </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="O">OutSource </asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
 <br />
<asp:Label ID="lblLaborType" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=rbtnType.ClientID%>").change(function () {
        var rbvalue = $("input[@name=<%=rbtnType.ClientID%>]:radio:checked").val();
        if (rbvalue == "C") {           
            $('#<%=lblLaborType.ClientID %>').html('Do this');
        }
        else if (rbvalue == "I") {
            $('#<%=lblLaborType.ClientID %>').html('else this');
        }
        else if (rbvalue == "O") {
            $('#<%=lblLaborType.ClientID %>').html('or else this');
        }
    });
});  </script>
```